# Select By Attribute - Get Parameter as Text - User input SQL ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, area, select-by-attribute, error-000358

I am trying to create a script that will search for suitable site locations.

I want to let the user input an area size (e.g. >20) to be searched but each time I run the script it comes up as

> Error 000358: Invalid expression. Failed to execute
>   (SelectLayerByAttribute).

This section of the code looks like:

```
inputvalue =arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
query = "POLY_AREA = " + inputvalue
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(featurelayer2, "NEW_SELECTION", query)
```

Comment: If you're evaluating a floating-point value for equivalence , it's unlikely to work correctly, but it won't  fail by 000358, which means you have delimiter issues in addition to a bad example.

Answer (score 1):

Use [AddFieldDelimiters](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/addfielddelimiters.htm) to get correct syntax:

> The field delimiters used in an SQL expression differ depending on the
>   format of the queried data. For instance, file geodatabases and
>   shapefiles use double quotation marks (" "), personal geodatabases use
>   square brackets ([ ]), and enterprise geodatabases don't use field
>   delimiters

If `POLY_AREA` is a text/string field, you need to add single quotes around the {1}: `'{1}'`

```
import arcpy

featurelayer2 = 'somelayer'
inputvalue =arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

sql = "{0} = {1}".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(datasource=featurelayer2, field='POLY_AREA'), inputvalue)

arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(in_layer_or_view=featurelayer2, where_clause=sql) #You dont need "NEW SELECTION" part, this is default
```

If you want the user to input the operator and area (like: >30) try:

```
"{0} {1}".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(datasource=featurelayer2, field='POLY_AREA'), inputvalue)
```